# How to group by on part of string

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I group data by a part of the string.

Example data:

```
StringA ValueA ValueB
47353-1 123    1440
47353-2 235    9472
47353-3  44     439
47355-1  21     482
```

Result wanted:

```
StringA Count SumA SumB
47353       3  402 11351 
47355       1   21   482
```

If I use Group by StringA, it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Derived table version. Very handy way to avoid typing complex aggregate functions twice:

```
select StringA, count(*), sum(ValueA) SumA, sum(ValueB) SumB
from
(
    select left(StringA, 5) StringA, ValueA, ValueB
    from tablename
)
group by StringA
```

ANSI SQL compliant! (Except `LEFT`, should be `substring(StringA from 1 for 5)`.)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go (data for testing) using a left with a CHARINDEX, this will allow for different length fields to be used if necessary.

Data for testing;

```
CREATE TABLE #TableName (StringA varchar(10), ValueA int, ValueB int)
INSERT INTO #TableName (StringA, ValueA, ValueB)
VALUES
('47353-1',123,1440)
,('47353-2',235,9472)
,('47353-3',44,439)
,('47355-1',21,482)
```

Actual Query;

```
SELECT
    LEFT(StringA,CHARINDEX('-',StringA,0)-1) StringA
    ,COUNT(StringA) Count
    ,SUM(ValueA) SumA
    ,SUM(ValueB) SumB
FROM
    #TableName
GROUP BY
    LEFT(StringA,CHARINDEX('-',StringA,0)-1)
```

Result

```
StringA   Count   SumA   SumB
47353     3       402    11351
47355     1       21     482
```

And don't forget;

```
DROP TABLE #TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query will give the required output :-

```
select distinct substring(stringA,1,charindex('-',StringA)-1) StringA, 
Count(StringA) over (partition by substring(stringA,1,charindex('-',StringA)-1)) Count, 
sum(ValueA) over (partition by substring(stringA,1,charindex('-',StringA)-1)) SumA, 
sum(ValueB) over (partition by substring(stringA,1,charindex('-',StringA)-1)) SumB 
from test
```

Output :-

```
StringA   Count   SumA   SumB
 47353      3      402   11351 
 47355      1       21     482
```